# Displaying GI in tab on any screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I want to display a GI on one of the tab in any screen.

For example, there is a new custom GI for OrderMargin which I want to display on SO screen on a new tab that will show the Order Margin for a particular order only.

OrderMargin is simple GI with SOOrder, SOLine and InventoryItem table joins and few columns required columns with margin calculations.

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you've created a GI called SalesOrderMargin with 2 hidden parameters:
[image]

To embed this GI into the Sales Orders page, you should follow the steps below:

1. Declare new unbound field for SOOrder to return absolute URL for the SalesOrderMargin GI:

   ```
   public class SOOrderExt : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
   {
       public abstract class marginGiUrl : IBqlField { }
       [PXString]
       [PXUIField(Visible = false)]
       public string MarginGiUrl
       {
           get
           {
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Base.OrderType) || 
                   string.IsNullOrEmpty(Base.OrderNbr)) return string.Empty;

               string inqName = "SalesOrderMargin";
               var url = new StringBuilder(PXGenericInqGrph.INQUIRY_URL)
                   .Append("?name=").Append(inqName)
                   .Append("&SOOrderType=").Append(Base.OrderType);
                   .Append("&SOOrderNbr=").Append(Base.OrderNbr);
                   .Append("&hidePageTitle=true");
               return PX.Common.PXUrl.SiteUrlWithPath().TrimEnd('/') + 
                   url.ToString().Remove(0, 1);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. On the Sales Orders screen, add new tab with a PXSmartPanel container set up to render as an iframe:

   ```
   <px:PXTabItem Text="Margins" >
       <Template>
           <px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" ID="panelMarginGI" RenderIFrame="True" 
               AutoSize-Enabled="true" SkinID="Frame" LoadOnDemand="true"/>
       </Template>
   </px:PXTabItem>
   ```
3. Place input control for the custom SOOrder unbound field declared in step 1 somewhere in the Sales Orders' top level PXFormView container (input control will always be hidden from the users and is only required to assign source URL for the PXSmartPanel):

   ```
   <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" 
       DataMember="Document" Caption="Order Summary"...>
       <Template>
           ...
           <px:PXTextEdit ID="edMarginGiUrl" runat="server" DataField="MarginGiUrl" />
       </Template>
   </px:PXFormView>
   ```
4. In SO301000.aspx insert JavaScript code to assign source URL for the PXSmartPanel:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       function commandResult(ds, context) {
           var commands = ["ReloadPage", "Save", "Cancel", "Insert", "First", "Previous", "Next", "Last"];
           if (commands.indexOf(context.command) >= 0) {
               var marginGiUrl = px_alls["edMarginGiUrl"];
               var smartpanel = px_alls["panelMarginGI"];
               if (marginGiUrl || smartpanel) {
                   var url = marginGiUrl.getValue();
                   smartpanel.setPageUrl(url);
                   smartpanel.repaint();
               }
           }
       }
   </script>
   ```
5. Subscribe to the CommandPerformed event of PXDataSource to invoke the commandResult JavaScript function:

   ```
   <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%" TypeName="PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry" PrimaryView="Document">
       <ClientEvents CommandPerformed="commandResult" />
       ...
   </px:PXDataSource>
   ```

And this is how your SalesOrderMargin GI should appear on the Sales Orders screen:
[image]